# Translate a doctrine2 model 'property' to a 'getter'?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I guess the answer to this question should be fairly simple, but I cannot seem to find it:

How do I properly transform a Doctrine Model property to the getter of that property, using the doctrine naming strategy?

```
<?php

class Bar {

    private $foo;

    public function getFoo() { }
}

$field = 'foo';
$getter = ...
```

Comment: If it's simple it's in the manual, so I wonder what's the problem to get it from there?

Comment: The problem is that I searched for it in the documentation and could not find the answer there.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're after?

```
$getter = sprinft('get%s', ucfirst($field));
```

This will handle this particular case at least.

Comment: You're example works fine, I'm actually doing something similar right now, but I'm wondering if there is a way to let some doctrine class do this for me, so my application won't break when, for example, Doctrine decides to change it's naming strategy in the future.